# Can I style out the .htaccess DirectoryIndex file?

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, directoryindex

I have a DirectoryIndex page that I want to style out with CSS. Instead of it looking like this:

[image: DirectoryIndex page]

Is it possible to make it look different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the header template in the .he access file then include your css in that.http://milianw.de/code-snippets/styling-apache-indexes has some useful info.